# Reordering output from Bash commands in a Python script

Tags: python, linux, bash

I am working on a Python script that deals with Wi-Fi access points. In the script I call os.system ("iwlist wlan0 s") to scan the wireless APs nearby.

There are only two pieces of information I need from each one: the name and the MAC address. I can grep the output to get a list of the names or the addresses, but is there a way to sort of line them up? For instance right now I can get:

```
ESSID: point 1
ESSID: point 2
etc,
```

And I can get

```
Address: gh:45:df:etc
Address: ofweiofjw
```

but is it possible to get the following?

```
name - address
name - address
```

I was thinking either in the Bash commands themselves or by taking the output in the Python script and editing it somehow.

Comment: How do you get the output as of now?

Comment: Show us what you've tried

Comment: what value is returned by `os.system("iwlist wlan0 s") `?

Comment: the whole thing is too long so heres one access point's output:

Comment: its still too long but its a bunch of info about the AP like the address channel frequency and its all like this:
Address: <MAC address>
Channel: 11
etc.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].